# What's the best way to re-install Ubuntu on my dual-boot system?

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, partitioning, dual-boot

I have a triple boot system with Windows,and Ubuntu 10.10, installed in that order, plus a "Data" Partition that has all my data, what I want to do is remove the 10.10, and replace 11.04

I would like to install a fresh copy of 11.04 and leave the rest of the system intact, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Most of the current 11.04 users have gone throw all the upgrades, that's the regular upgrade process during pre-release. The chances of getting a broken system is related to the current archive/development status, not to the upgrades.

Comment: More then that, I want a fresh install of 11.04 to start fresh with

Comment: No release is "fresher" than your's when you upgrade now. You need to wait for Alpha2 coming Feb 3rd (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyReleaseSchedule). If you don't boot into it anyway you could also wait for the final release to have things stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you use grub to boot? What you would have to do (**at your own risk**) is to reinstall the conventional way, but choose to use the partition/hard drive that 11.04 is on to install your fresh copy.

Comment: It works, though grub (the MBR bit) will be *owned* by the 11.04 installation. Which isn't a problem, but something to keep in mind.

Comment: he would just need to do grub install from the 10.10 installation later.

Comment: How do i know what partition 11.04 is intalled on, and how do I tell ubuntu to install over it?

Comment: If you can boot into 11.04 (don't apply updates) and do `sudo fdisk-l` it should tell you which is which, or you can use disk utility. The drive that 11.04 is using will be mounted as `/`, aka the root partition.

Answer (score 0):

Just Install Ubuntu Normally, Grub will do the magic I guess.